# Required plug-in 'org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime' could not be found

Tags: eclipse, plugins, junit, pde

I'm working with Eclipse Indigo and need to use Junit PDE to test my plugin functionality. I installed Junit, and these two plugins:

http://market.eclipsesource.com/yoxos/node/junit.extensions.eclipse.quick.pde.source.feature.feature.group?mpc=true&mpc_state=

http://market.eclipsesource.com/yoxos/node/junit.extensions.eclipse.quick.pde.feature.feature.group?mpc=true&mpc_state=

But when I tried to run my test case (Run->Run Configurations->JUnit Plug-in Test) I keep obstaining the following error: Required plug-in 'org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime' could not be found.

If someone could telle what else do I need, or what I'm doing wrong I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if you have the org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime installed by going to Help->About Eclipse, Installation Details, then finding the plugin in the Plug-ins tab (column Plug-In Id). If it's not there, you can install it from the Eclipse update site. If it is there, then you have a correupted installation, and it's probably a good idea to restart from scratch with a new installation of the Indigo PDE.

Answer (score 0):

Does it look a bit like [Right target platform for running JUnit plugin tests in Eclipse Indigo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534101/right-target-platform-for-running-junit-plugin-tests-in-eclipse-indigo)

Could you share your `.launch`-config with us? Does "Validate before launch" give any error? Did you setup the correct JUnit-dependencies in the build-path? As far as I know, `junit.runtime` refers to JUnit 3.

What surprises me a bit is that you had to install JUnit---if you're using the standard Eclipse JDT, JUnit is included. What did you do exactly?